# How to Hide and show Items using a toggle button in android studio

Tags: java, android, charts

I'm trying to display 4 charts on a single activity. I want to give the user the option of choosing what kind of graph to show by providing the toggle button.

E.g.:

These are the following graphs which show energy consumption:

- Elec Bar Graph
- Elec Line Chart
- Gas Bar Graph
- Gas Line Chart

There are two toggle buttons, one for electricity and one for Gas. ***When clicking on the electricity toggle button, you should be able to switch between bar graph and line chart only for electricity. Same thing is applied for the gas button.***

**Problem:** After clicking on the Electricity Toggle Button to see line chart for electricity and then clicking on the Gas Toggle Button to see line chart for gas consumption the output is: two line charts for both electricity and gas, whereas it should just show the line chart for gas consumption upon clicking the gas toggle button.

This is a brief snippet of the code:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.electricityButton:

boolean check = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();
                if (check) {

                    CreateElectricityLineGraph();
                    GasLineGraph.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ElecbarChart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ElecLineChart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else {
                                CreateElectricityBarGraph();
                                GasbarChart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                     ElectricityLineChart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                GasLineChart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                ElectricitybarChart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  System.out.println("Elec Bar Chart Now Visible");
                            }
break;
case R.id.GasButton:


                boolean c = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();
                if (c) {
                    ElectricityLineChart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    CreateGasLineGraph();
                    ElectricitybarChart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    GasLineChart2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    System.out.println("Reached the end of if statement 2");

                }
                else{
                    CreateGasBarGraph();
                    ElectricitybarChart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ElectricityLineChart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    GasLineChart2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    GasbarChart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    System.out.println("The Gas Bar graph has been made visible");



                }
                break;
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to `GasLineChart` and `GasLineChart2` both are visible in checked condition. you have not make `GasLineChart` invisible in any condition and also make `GasLineChart2` visible on 2nd Condition

Comment: Hi, I did make GasLineChart2 visible in the second condition and as for making them invisible, in the second toggle button, i have included the code GasLineChart.SetVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) - isnt that the way to go about making the chart invisible ?

Comment: but you had included GasLineChart invisible in only "electricityButton :- not checked condition" which is never happening as you are making both button checked

Comment: Right, i think i understand. So what you're saying is, i have made the GasChart Invisible in the electricity button but not in the Gas button, so then do i need to make the gas chart invisible in the gas button bit? Apologies if i have not understood you correctly.